# How can I simulate SSB distortion caused by envelope delay?

Tags: pwm

Kahn first proposed envelope elimination and restoration (EER) in the 1950's to produce SSB with a nonlinear RF section. Modern IC technology makes it easy to produce the high-power AF envelope signal with pulse-width modulation (PWM) and a class D amplifier followed by an LC lowpass filter, but the filter delay may cause distortion by misaligning the envelope modulation and phase drive signals.

I attempted to determine the tolerable delay by simulating an SSB generator in LTspice: behavioral voltage sources produce the *I* and *Q* signals from two audio tones.  The *I* and *Q* signals then modulate an RF carrier in quadrature to produce SSB, which is easily verified.

While adding a time delay term to the *I* and *Q* sources obviously creates a temporal shift in the envelope signal, I conclude there's no distortion because the FFT of the resulting SSB signal is the same.

How can I analyze this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I can't quite understand what you are trying to do. I looked at an old paper on SSB by EER and it looks like a way to generate SSB while using a non-linear RF amp as the final.

In the paper they first generate an RF SSB signal with a conventional method (for that era) and then AM detect it to generate the SSB baseband signal. The RF SSB signal is then limited (envelope removal) and used to drive a non linear class C amplifier. The supply of the class -C amplifier is then varied with the AM detected SSB envelope previously recovered (envelope restoration) and the resulting output of the class C amplifier is a larger RF SSB signal. The main benefit in this scheme is the use of a non-linear RF amplifier.

In the block diagram I describe,  simple, constant delay in either the RF path or the audio path will not create distortion, just delay. The type of delay to be concerned (in the audio path) is "group delay" or "delay distortion" which is a confusing term for a delay across a frequency band that is not constant. A non-constant time delay causes a non-linear phase response, which can then cause amplitude distortion in a signal that has more than one frequency in it at a time.

Was the delay that you were creating constant with frequency, or varying? I assume really extreme group delay would distort a voice audio signal, but perhaps you are trying to pass higher bandwidth data signals. If you are trying to generate some sort of data modulation over SSB there are plenty of papers how much delay distortion a data signal can tolerate.

Answer (score -1):

Well, that's because I-Q is the wrong domain. If you delay I and Q equally, that's just a time delay of *the whole signal*, which is boring. Delaying them unequally is also not the thing you want to study. You need to simulate the EER part of EER, by converting from I-Q to phase-magnitude, then delaying phase with respect to magnitude, then converting back.

As for doing that in a circuit simulator... well, I have limited experience with those, but that sounds hard. Like, almost as hard as doing it in real life. Like, you probably can't develop a "perfect" circuit with no distortion, and then add imperfections on command.

But if you ignore the circuit-simulation level and just do things in software, then you can sandwich delays (or arbitrary FIR filters, or arbitrary nonlinearities) in between a Hilbert transform and an inverse Hilbert transform easily enough. So that's the approach I would take if I wanted to answer this sort of question.

Of course, you might use SPICE to figure out the impulse response of *one part* of a theoretical design, and then plug that result in as the "arbitrary FIR filter" in the previous step :)